# Javascript loop - hide animated div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm going to try to make this as descriptive as possible, my apologies in advance if I have difficulties explaining what it is exactly that I am trying to do.

**Written Description:**

So I am creating a web based game in javascript. This game is a 2 player shooter game. So far, when a player 'shoots' another player, it spawns an animated div which goes from its start (at the gun of player1) to the end of the screen where it then gets removed (using removeChild from the div it was spawned in.)

The problem is that when the bullet 'hits' the player, it jsut keeps on going until the end of the screen. My code does register whether or not the bullet hits the player, but when it does hit the player, I would like it to dissappear either on the player or right after it passes the player, so that it has the effect that it penetrates the player instead of just passing over the player.

**Now let me be more specific.**

```
$("#bullet").animate({
    marginLeft: '100%'
}, 1000, function(){            
    document.getElementById("thegame").removeChild("#bullet");
});
```

basically this is the code that spawns the 'bullet'

now lets say that I wanted to get the bullet to disappear after it's margin passed 70% by doing some sort of loop that checks its position as the animated div is traveling..

how would I do this? (the bullet is #bullet)
I tried doing a loop for this but i must have failed because it didn't work.

Comment: `$(this).remove()` instead of `document.getElementById("thegame").removeChild("#bullet");`

Comment: Do you have some code executing when the player is hit by the bullet?  $("#bullet").remove() should work in that case

Comment: using .remove() doesn't work on internet explorer, sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `step` option of `.animate()` , `.stop()`

```js
var money = $("#thegame span")[0];

$("#bullet").animate({
  marginLeft: '100%'
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  step: function(now, fx) {
    // calling `.stop()` triggers `.fail` callback
    if (now > 70) $(fx.elem).stop()
  },
  done: function() {
      document.getElementById("thegame").removeChild(money);
  },
  fail: function() {
    document.getElementById("thegame").removeChild(money);
    console.log(this, this.style.marginLeft)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="bullet">abc</div>
<div id="thegame"><span>thegame</span></div>
```

Comment: Would I need to define the variable now as being the margin for #bullet?

Comment: _"Would I need to define the variable now as being the margin for #bullet?"_ `now` is the `Number` parameter representing the unit of the animated property; e.g., `margin-left` incrementing during animation to `100` , or `"100%"` . If changed `"100%"` to `"50%"`, `now` would increment to `50` . See http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options

Comment: _"So how you have it right now , checks whether or not the margin is greater then 70"_ Yes. _"or do i need to define now or anything like that?"_ No, `now` is defined by jQuery  by default; should correspond to the `unit` , as a `Number`, of the property value being animated.

Comment: thanks... this is the correct solution to my problem. Appreciate it

Comment: Question... so it is working at at a margin of 70% the div is disappearing, however, everything under done: is not running, instead it is running the code under fail: ... I mean it's working when i just put the code i need ran under fail: instead of done: but just wondering why this is

Comment: @JasonRigley _"just wondering why this is "_ See http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options _"fail
Type: Function( Promise animation, Boolean jumpedToEnd )
A function to be called when the animation on an element fails to complete (its Promise object is rejected)."_ `.stop()` rejects jQuery promise object associated with the current animation, triggering `.fail()`. Could alternatively use `.always()` _"A function to be called when the animation on an element completes or stops without completing (its Promise object is either resolved or rejected)"_ https://jsfiddle.net/hecfm8je/

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()`for this purpose,

```
function myfun(){
   setTimeout(function(){$("#welcome").show(100)}, 2000);
   setTimeout(function(){$("#welcome").hide(500)}, 7000);
}
```

`setInterval()`would invoke the supplied code for every time interval that you gave